# What causes "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, multipartform-data, photo

I want to upload the user profile photo. I am using the following code. It successfully uploads the photo and saves it in the database but at the end, the following exception occurs. I don't know why it is happening.

**FileUploadController**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uploadUserProfilePhoto/{userId}", produces="application/json")   
public @ResponseBody UserPhoto handleUserProfileFileUpload(Authentication authentication, @PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) 
        return photoService.createUserPhoto(file , userId);
    else 
        throw new RuntimeException( "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because the file was empty");
}
```

**uploadPhotoService**

```
@Transactional
public UserPhoto createUserPhoto(MultipartFile file, long userId){
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
    UserPhoto previousPhoto = userPhotoRepository.findByUserId(userId);   
    if(previousPhoto!=null){    
        deletePhoto(previousPhoto.getPath());
        return  updatePhotoWithFile(file, previousPhoto);
    }
    else{
        UserPhoto userPhoto = new UserPhoto();
        userPhoto.setUser(user);
        userPhoto = userPhotoRepository.save(userPhoto);
        user.setProfilePhoto(userPhoto);
        try {
            String extension = photoUtils.getExtension(file);
            photoUtils.assertValidExtenstion(extension);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File(staticPath + "userPhotos/" + userPhoto.getId() + extension)));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
            stream.close();
            userPhoto.setPath("userPhotos/" + userPhoto.getId() + extension);
            userPhotoRepository.save(userPhoto);

            return userPhoto;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because of server error", e);
        }
    }
}

private UserPhoto updatePhotoWithFile(MultipartFile file, UserPhoto previousPhoto){
    try {

        String extension = photoUtils.getExtension(file);
        photoUtils.assertValidExtenstion(extension);
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File(staticPath + "userPhotos/" + previousPhoto.getId() + extension)));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
        stream.close();
        previousPhoto.setPath("userPhotos/" + previousPhoto.getId() + extension);
        userPhotoRepository.save(previousPhoto);
        return previousPhoto;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because of server error", e);
    }
}

private void deletePhoto(String path)
{
    Path pathOfFile=Paths.get(staticPath+path);
    try {
        Files.deleteIfExists(pathOfFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:355) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:324) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:580) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:502) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:375) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    ... 100 common frames omitted
```

Comment: does it take too long to finish this request?

Comment: @DemonColdmist Yup

Comment: maybe it was timeout caused this exception.